# video.js theme with errors

Tags: html, video.js

not working vjs-theme-city. Need help, thx.
css is connected, js is connected. 
I did everything according to the instructions.
I took the template from the official site. The normal version works, but the city does not.

```
<head>
        <link
                href="https://unpkg.com/@videojs/themes@1/dist/city/index.css"
                rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 (for Video.js versions prior to v7) -->
        <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <video
            id="my-video"
            class="video-js vjs-theme-city"
            controls
            preload="auto"
            width="640"
            height="264"
            poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg"
            data-setup="{}"
    >
        <source src="MY_VIDEO.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="MY_VIDEO.webm" type="video/webm" />
        <p class="vjs-no-js">
            To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
            web browser that
            <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank"
            >supports HTML5 video</a
            >
        </p>
    </video>

    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.7.6/video.js"></script>
    </body>
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/himfF.png)

[codepen](https://codepen.io/Cod3c/pen/LYpaGmM)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the regular Video.js CSS, as well as the theme.

Answer (score 0):

You are not loading the videojs css. The theme is simply modifying some elements and not rewriting the whole player design.